# Creating a Static Structure which array use different data types

Tags: c, list, struct

I'm creating a struct like this:

```
typedef struct stat{
    char name[50], type[50];
    double x, y, lar, alt;
    
} info;

typedef struct list{
    int prim, livre;
    info A[];
    
} LS;

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    LS *mylist = malloc(sizeof(LS) + n);
    
    mylist->info->A[3] = 1.5;
    printf("%lf", mylist->info->A[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I know it's possible to create a flexible array type inside a struct, however i don't know how can i access the array to use it. How should i do that and how it would work for strings?

I want to use an array(which size will be defined by the user input) and inside of it i will store a struct with name, type, x, y, lar, alt in position A[0], another in position A[1] and so on.

Comment: Remember that the size you pass to `malloc` is the size in *bytes*. When you add `n` in the call, you only add `n` bytes for the allocation, but you want to add `n * sizeof(info)` bytes: `malloc(sizeof(LS) + (n * sizeof(info))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) exactly like any other structure member.

In your case you access it as `mylist->A`, and each individual element of the array as `info->A[i]` (for valid values of `i`).

Then since each element of the array is a structure *object* use use normal dot-notation `.` to access the members of the structures in the array:

```
mylist->A[3].x = 1.5;
printf("%f\n", mylist->A[3].x);
```

Comment: What about strings? Tried to change "x" to "name" and it returned assignment to expression with array type

Comment: @FelipeWatanabe: In C strings are just *null terminated char arrays*, and essentially arrays. You cannot assign to a string but must copy into them with `strcpy` (or `strncpy`).

Comment: @FelipeWatanabe That's because you can't assign to arrays, not a problem with flexible array members. If you have a "string" you need to copy to it:  `strcpy(mylist->A[3].name, "foobar")`